# Sharing a photo from an ios app

Tags: ios

Given that I have a UIImage instance in my app how could I get
ios to show the image sharing dialog (Mail, add to notes, twitter, fb,
save image, etc)

Upon a cursory look to PHAsset I haven't found anything prominent :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can search for **UIActivityViewController**. This class will display a dialog, having all sharing apps listed within dialog.

Comment: tnx, that is it I guess